# How to config SpringBoot 3.1.3 to use log4j2 - getting the java.lang.StackOverflowError

Tags: spring-boot, apache-tomee

I followed this [link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.2.9.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/howto-logging.html#:%7E:text=To%20use%20Log4j%202%2C%20simply,-boot-starter-log4j%20.&text=The%20use%20of%20one%20of,using%20Log4j%20or%20Log4j) to config my Springboot web app to use log4j2 as its logging mechanism.  This web app is running on a TOMEE 9 server.  Unfortunately, the app encountered the java.lang.StackOverflowError and failed to start.  Any idea what might be causing such an error?

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.jul.Log4jBridgeHandler.getLog4jLogger(Log4jBridgeHandler.java:229)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.jul.Log4jBridgeHandler.publish(Log4jBridgeHandler.java:194)
    at java.logging/java.util.logging.Logger.log(Logger.java:980)
    at java.logging/java.util.logging.Logger.doLog(Logger.java:1007)
    at java.logging/java.util.logging.Logger.logp(Logger.java:1173)
    at org.apache.tomee.jul.formatter.log.JULLogger.log(JULLogger.java:174)
    at org.apache.tomee.jul.formatter.log.JULLogger.debug(JULLogger.java:102)
    at org.apache.tomee.jul.formatter.log.TomEELog.debug(TomEELog.java:124)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1291)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomEEWebappClassLoader.loadClass(TomEEWebappClassLoader.java:209)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1257)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.jul.Log4jBridgeHandler.getLog4jLogger(Log4jBridgeHandler.java:229)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.jul.Log4jBridgeHandler.publish(Log4jBridgeHandler.java:194)
    at java.logging/java.util.logging.Logger.log(Logger.java:980)
    at java.logging/java.util.logging.Logger.doLog(Logger.java:1007)
    at java.logging/java.util.logging.Logger.logp(Logger.java:1173)
    at org.apache.tomee.jul.formatter.log.JULLogger.log(JULLogger.java:174)
    at org.apache.tomee.jul.formatter.log.JULLogger.debug(JULLogger.java:102)
    at org.apache.tomee.jul.formatter.log.TomEELog.debug(TomEELog.java:124)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1291)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomEEWebappClassLoader.loadClass(TomEEWebappClassLoader.java:209)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1257)
    . . .
```

Comment: Usually it still happen when you are using 2 or more different libraries for logging in project and it create conflict. Can you share dependency tree of your `pom.xml` or `build.gradle` ?

Comment: Thanks Andrei.  Odd enough, I got it to work by not using the "spring-boot-starter-log4j", like the Spring site suggested.  Instead, I simply adds the "log4j-api" and "log4j-core" to my pom.xml, like I usually do, and it started to work.

Comment: Happy to hear it, good luck